Reading duplicate emails even after providing timestamp in since in imap-flow?
  await imapClient.mailboxOpen("INBOX");
  const listOfMessages = await Promise.all(
    subjectArrayForMails[tenant].map(async (subject: string) => {
      return await imapClient.search({
        since: data.data[0].time,
        subject: subject,
        from: senderMail,
      });
    })
  );

The above is the logic from where I am reading the mails according to tenant wise I have subject array which is like below
["Report A"]
The timestamp I am passing is like below
"2024-09-05 07:07:00"
Even after passing this timestamp it still the reads the mail in which the time was before that the above timestamp.
I am expecting it to take the timestamp correctly
